# Syntax X Bar Tree - Complements & Adjuncts

Tags: syntax, x-bar-theory, adjuncts, complement

I am having some trouble to identify Complements and Adjuncts. I have the following sentence:

"A picture of the accident of Gabriel is saved on the album with a pink cover with the white dots"

- of the accident
- of Gabriel
- with a pink cover with the white dots

Are these Complements or Adjuncts? If you can explain me way better

Comment: "A picture of the accident of Gabriel" doesn't make any sense to me. I have no idea what relationship it is trying to express between Gabriel and the picture (or the accident). Since the distinction between adjuncts and complements is partly semantic, this makes it impossible for me to answer your question.

Comment: Yeah I also haven't worked with such sentences, and this doesn't quite make sense to me. Just by looking at it at first glance I thought they could be complement of the pictures, since they are describing about what, of whom the picture is. But I am still not sure about.

Comment: "A picture of the accident of Gabriel" seems to mean "a picture of how Gabriel got into an accident", like a picture of a car hitting Gabriel. There's another much more ambiguous issue, whether "with the white dots" refers to the pink cover of the album or to the picture of the accident itself.

Comment: But _the accident of Gabriel_ is so unnatural a phrase that it is not clear that that is what it means.

Comment: Where did you get the sentence from?

Comment: We create them based in similar sentences from old exams for practice, this was based on: "A painting of the destruction of Hiroshima is hanging at the hall with a golden ceiling
with a white door"

Comment: Normally in Carnie's exercises are a bit clear, like: I bought a book of poems with a black cover from the library by Edgar Allan Poe. You can keep adding and looping such as an Adjunct would do.

Comment: Now that I see after doing one replacement/substitution I kinda ended up to the conclusion that "of the destruction" is a Compliment and the rest are just Adjuncts, they can be substituted, reorganized without losing the meaning within their NP.

Comment: Consider this: complements are either obligatory or they have to be licensed by the head word. Optional elements in clause (not phrase) structure may be adjuncts. Now apply that 'rule' to your examples and see what you come up with.